# How to add a directory as a root node in Treeviewer?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, jface

How to add a directory as a root node in `Treeviewer`. I want to display file structure from my current directory i.e from `C:/documents`. I have the program to display all the files in the cureent system. But I only want to display from a particular directory. I want to display only from current directory. eg if i have c,d,e,f drives on a system. I want to display only c drive.

```
final TreeViewer tv = new TreeViewer(composite);
tv.getTree().setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.FILL_BOTH));
tv.setContentProvider(new FileTreeContentProvider());
tv.setLabelProvider(new FileTreeLabelProvider());
tv.setInput("null"); // pass a non-null that will be ignored
```

How to set a directory as input? What should I pass to `setInput()`?

Comment: can you explain your requirement?

Comment: Is `FileTreeContentProvider` from an API, if so which one? Is it a class that you wrote yourself?

Answer (score 2):

First of all set the input of the `viewer` to the directory you want your root to be. For example if it is a `java.io.File` object then your `FileTreeContentProvider`'s `getElements(Object)` method should look something like this:

```java
public Object[] getElements(Object inputElement) {
    return getChildren(inputElement);
}

public Object[] getChildren(Object parentElement) {
    File dir = (File) parentElement;
    return dir.listFiles();
}
```